# Flex - Clear DateField programmatically

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, datefield

I cannot find any way to clear a `DateField` control programmatically after either a user has selected a date, or after I set `myDateField.selectedDate` via code.

Documentation only states how to clear it if a user selects the date again.

But doing `myDateField.selectedDate = myDateField.selectedDate` doesn't work

I have tried all the obvious, `myDateField.selectedDate = null`, `myDateField.text = ""` - but nothing seems to be doing the trick.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made a minimal test example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="horizontal">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
        private function clearDate():void   {
            testField.selectedDate = null;
        }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
    <mx:DateField id="testField"/>
    <mx:Button label="Clear" click="clearDate();"/>
</mx:Application>
```

and it seems to work fine. Are you sure there isn't some baffling bug in your code?

(This is with FB 3.2 here, by the way, in case it is a version issue.)

Answer (score 0):

It works on FB2 too.